# W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

I used to have the "This site is experiencing technical difficulties." error message and went to CPanel to change the wp-config file and change the WP_Debug false to true but it's showing more error. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the plugin? In which code line does the error appear?

Comment: hello, the site is now okay. Thank you for responding! I just disabled some of the plugins and is now okay.